# Instabot: ERROR - Request returns 429 error

Tags: python, instagram

I have posted yesterday that I am getting:

> ERROR - Request returns 429 error!

I have tried running it just as:

```
from instabot import Bot
import time

bot = Bot()
bot.login(username="username", password="password")
image = "1.png"
bot.upload_photo(image, caption="")
```

But it still gave me the same error as when I ran the below code yesterday. I can manually login and upload to Instagram; Why the bot can not do it?

```
from instabot import Bot
import time

bot = Bot()
image = 1
bot.login(username="username", password="password")

while image < 10001:

    photo = str(image)
    bot.upload_photo(f"{photo}.png", caption="")
    image += 1
    time.sleep(3600)
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 429 means sending to many requests. 10000 images might do that. Try sending less requests to the server.

Comment: I have tried it with less images, but I have a sleep timer of 1 hour on the while loop so why is this an issue?

Comment: Well Mozilla has this to say about how to fix it: A Retry-After header might be included to this response indicating how long to wait before making a new request.

Comment: Mozilla says retry after 3600 seconds which I already did